# Basic design for a socks proxy

Tags: .net, sockets, networking, tcp, proxy

I've written a fairly simple SOCKS4/5 proxy in .Net. It does the following:

- Opens a `TcpListener()` on a port
- Fires up a `TcpClient()` to handle any incoming connection
- Parses/handles initial header/request stuff
- Opens a corresponding `TcpClient()` to the remote host
- Echos data back/forth between the two connections.

It seems to work fine for most things (web browsing, etc.). However, I'm getting some weird errors when attempting to run OpenVPN via the proxy (Bad encapsulated packet length from peer).

My question - is using a TcpClient adequate for creating a socks proxy? Or do I fundamentally need to do something more low-level?

Comment: Since you did not show your code, there is no way to answer this.

Comment: @RemyLebeau in this case, i'm not asking whether there is something wrong with my code - i'm asking whether it is possible to build a fully functional socks proxy using the .Net TcpClient(), or whether I would need to use something lower level. Code is irrelevant.

Comment: Of course it is possible, and you already outlined how to do it.  The only thing lower-level then `TcpClient` is PInvoke to the Winsock API directly. That is not your issue. The fact that "most things" work shows that your proxy works in general. The fact that OpenVPN specifically does not work likely means you have a bug in your proxy code that is corrupting the VPN data. I am not familiar with OpenVPN, but do keep in mind that SOCKS is not the only type of proxy available, so maybe OpenVPN is not using SOCKS to begin with?

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for the feedback. I did manage to get a workaround by using port forwarding over SSH. Never did manage to get the proxy working with OpenVPN. I'll take this up with the OpenVPN group and dig into it more.